# Reverse proxy does not work with win DNS

Tags: dns, reverse-proxy

I am trying to resolve my reverse proxy from my dns but it does not work. Please have a look and suggest me how to resolve the workstation problem from the local network. It is working fine from the internet.
My proxy is apache2. I am using windows 10 workstations and windows server as domain controller and dns server.
[image]